# How to send SMTP message from Onion SMTP server

Tags: c#, .net-core, smtp, smtpclient, tor

I try to send mail with SMTP from onion smtp (mail2tor service), but it doesn`t working, I just don`t get this mail.

```
SmtpClient Smtp = new  SmtpClient("smtp.xc7tgk2c5onxni2wsy76jslfsitxjbbptejnqhw6gy2ft7khpevhc7ad.onion", 25);
        Smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("tillicollapse@mail2tor.com", "********");
        Smtp.EnableSsl = false;

        MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
        Message.From = new MailAddress("tillicollapse@mail2tor.com");
        Message.To.Add(new MailAddress("tillicollapse@mail2tor.com"));
        Message.Subject = "test";
        Message.Body = "test test";
    Smtp.Send(Message);
```

I expect, that this mail will send to my mail.
I try to check settings in mail2tor, if they are require confirmation for third party applications.
I try to use other ports, like 587, 465
I try to enable/disable SSL

Comment: Is that all your code or are you posting a portion of it?

Comment: Did you forget - Smtp.Send(Message)?

Comment: No, i just forget to add Smtp.Send(Message) to this embed, I have it in code

Comment: This is just a portion, that is responsible for sending e-mail

Comment: What is big long string after smtp - shouldnt it be :mail.onionmail.org

Comment: I don`t know, but this has written on his site 
SMTP Address: xc7tgk2c5onxni2wsy76jslfsitxjbbptejnqhw6gy2ft7khpevhc7ad.onion:25

Comment: The SMTP address is `xc7tgk2c5onxni2wsy76jslfsitxjbbptejnqhw6gy2ft7khpevhc7ad.onion` and does not begin with `smtp.` like in the code posted. Also, is this C# SMTP connection configured to use SOCKS5 so it can connect to .onion domains?